# MySQL Load Data Local Infile Correct Query Format

Tags: mysql, csv

I am am trying to import some data from a csv into MySQL, converting columns from csv into columns in SQL. My query is below, along with a sample of the csv.

The problem is that the query I'm using isn't correctly matching up the rows/columns.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/ccgifts/tower/STOCK30112018201445.csv' 
INTO TABLE temp_table 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY 'n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES 
(
`web_store_price`, `stk_webtax_group`, `trade_price`, `tax_level`, 
`tax_group`, `supplier_name`, `supplier_code`, `subcat_name`,
`subcat_code`, `stock_supplier_code`, `short_description`, `rrp`, 
`retail_price`, `qty`, `plu`, `gst_payable`, `gst_credit`, 
`extra_description`, `description`, `department_name`, `department`, 
`cost_price`, `cost_ex`, `category_name`, `category`, 
`barcode`, `author`
)
```

And here's the first few lines of the csv, as copied from TextEdit on Mac

[image: Screenshot of .csv]

When importing it only did 3 rows and stopped and the columns were not aligning/matching up to the ones in the csv. My gut tells me something is wrong with the query and the delimiter used for designating new rows/columns?

Comment: `LINES TERMINATED BY 'n' `? You're missing the backslash before `n`.

Comment: duh! Let me try!

Comment: Yep OK running via SSH I was able to import 902 lines before it crapped out with 3,202 warnings. Something in the formatting is breaking it. I'll take a look at that 902nd row and see what's funky around there.

Comment: Maybe that row has a field containing comma and surrounded by quotes.

Comment: Add `FIELDS OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\'`

Comment: Thanks @Barmar I will check that out!